# cupy.cuda.memory.OutOfMemoryError: out of memory to allocate

Tags: python, chainer, cuda, gpu

タイトル通りのエラーが出ています。

```
python gpu cuda cudnn chainer
```

対策を教えていただきたいです。
プログラムの構成上delを実行したり画像処理を行っているのですが、画像サイズを小さくする、バッチサイズを下げる、ネットワークを変えることはできないのです。。。

わがままで申し訳ないのですが、どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: このエラーが出るプログラムの例は公開できますでしょうか？　エラーだけから具体的な原因を推測するのは難しいので、もし可能であれば[最小限の・自己完結した・確認可能なサンプルコード](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)を追記して頂けると回答が集まりやすいです。質問文下の「編集」から追記できますので、よろしければお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

マルチGPUを使わないのであれば，[F.forget](https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/chainer.functions.forget.html)という関数があります．この関数は，中間特徴の`.array`を削除することでメモリを空けることができます．

また，マルチGPUを使っていいのであれば，[マルチGPUを使ったデータ並列化](https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/guides/gpu.html#data-parallel-computation-on-multiple-gpus-with-trainer)も参考になります．
この場合，最低限バッチサイズ1でforward-backwardが通ることが条件になります．